# preserving and recreating state via the URL

Tags: javascript, url, web, state

Imagine the following scenario:

The user goes to `https://mywebsite.com`, searches for something and hits `[submit]`. The results are displayed and the URL is now `https://mywebsite.com/floobah?q=burp`. The user clicks on an anchor which scrolls the page down to a div a choice of ways to visualize the result. The URL is now `https://mywebsite.com/floobah?q=burp#viz`. The user chooses the pie chart widget and displays the pie and associated data. The URL is now `https://mywebsite.com/floobah?q=burp&chart=pie&sort=asc#viz`.

Then the user sends the URL to a friend. When its recipient opens that URL, the state is restored exactly as what it was for the sender. In other words, the URL is parsed and the actions performed to restore the state… the query is performed, the page scrolls down to the *viz* section, the pie chart opens up and the associated data is shown sorted as requested.

I am doing this right now by parsing the URL and replaying all the steps. But surely there must be a library already for doing this, no? To sum, I want the state of a page encoded in the URL which can be shared and then recreated by the recipient of the URL bookmark.

**Update 1:** A problem with my URL as noted above `https://mywebsite.com/floobah?q=burp&chart=pie&sort=asc#viz` is that there is no way to differentiate between a true query param such as `q=burb` and something that was a result of clicking on an element with an event listener attached to let, for example, `chart=pie&soft=asc`. I need to be able to differentiate commands for handling events and the query string and hash (`#viz`)

**Update 2:** So, I have three sets of params: the queryString that is processed on the server, the events that are processed in the client, and the hash fragment which specifies an anchor on the page to which the browser scrolls. What if I mark the events with `!` ? Imagine `https://mywebsite.com/floobah?q=burp!makePieChart!sortAscending#viz`. The queryString `q=burp` is processed by the server and returned to the client which scrolls down to `#viz` and fires events to `makePieChart` and `sortAscending`. Thoughts?

Comment: Using the URL to convey this is exactly what you should be doing IMO.  HTTP is stateless so follow the convention of deriving your server response and initial state from a function of the user requesting and the path/query params.

Comment: If you use plain HTML this works out of the box.

Comment: all server-side frameworks I know of allow you to easily parse the query parameters of the URL, and decide on the content accordingly. As for the hash-routing, that is something that happens with plain HTML (but can be manipulated with javascript if you want to).